# What do these numbers and symbols mean in my Documents folder in Finder?

Tags: icloud, finder

My Documents are uploaded automatically to iCloud, I recently put a bunch of photos into a subdirectory under `~/Documents/Old Photos` and noticed Finder is syncing that directory to iCloud.  However the numbers are a little confusing.

[image: Finder Window]

See in the middle of the window there's an up-arrow with `159.28 GB` next to it.  What exactly is this?  I thought it was the amount of data left to upload, however it is going up and down rather than just down.  Maybe MacOS is just doing a bad job calculating the remaining data...

Any insight would be helpful

Comment: after some time the numbers do appear to be consistently (albeit slowly) going down and no longer going up.  Maybe there was recalculation going on when I first noticed the numbers as it was immediately after a system restart

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out.  So when I click the pie shown by the arrow below
[image: Finder Window]

this pops up another window showing the progress of my uploads

[image: Finder Progress]

So I guess the figures do represent the data remaining for that directory, maybe MacOS just made up the numbers at the beginning

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`